# Jsp com scriptlets, taglib ou jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

Olá, acabei de me registrar e está está sendo minha primeira pergunta. Desculpe qualquer regra que eu não esteja seguindo com esta publicação.

Bom, a pouco tempo atrás comecei a aprender jsp na faculdade, foi introduzido um pouco de scriptlet(acho que é isso <% %>) e taglib () e aí muito jstl. Dando uma navegada por aí não consegui achar todas as respostas para minhas dúvidas, mesmo aqui no stack tanto em inglês como português, mas acabei vendo um pessoal não recomendando usar scriptlet, por você não conseguir reaproveitar o código, etc. Alguns dizendo para não usar apenas jstl e algumas outras coisas. Foi aí que fiquei confuso, afinal qual a melhor prática? Usar scriptlet, jstl ou misturar tudo? Vi até gente não recomendando mais jsp, por que o jsf parou de usá-lo como template padrão. Obrigado!

Comment: [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707036/java-ee-vs-jsp-vs-jsf)  tem um pessoal dizendo que dá pra substituir o JSP e que ele só está sendo mantido para aplicações legado.

Comment: Não foi isso que eu entendi daquela resposta, mas enfim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu penso que existem vários caminhos que você pode seguir, falar de desenvolvimento e da construção de aplicações é muito amplo, alguns exemplos seriam aplicações action-based e component-base, mas tanto uma como a outra existem certos padrões que você pode seguir, o Java é muito amplo você mode até mesmo fazer uma miscelânia de tecnologias que iria funcionar(poderia ter sérios problemas mas em uma app básica você faria renderizar), porém renderizar não é tudo, quando você começa a desenvolver sua aplicação ela vai se tornardo maior e você começa a ver os problemas que tem para resolver, seja de desempenho, layout, integrações etc... quando vocẽ escreve muitos scriptlets na própria página JSP você esta levando uma responsabilidade que deveria de estar no servidor Java para a sua JSP que é onde deveria ficar apenas seu código HTML, o fato é que devido essa amplitude permissiva que o Java tem acaba fazendo com que desenvolvedores façam tudo que é m. em um software.

Scriptlets não devem estar nas páginas JSP porque não é responsábilidade do designer conhecer Java nem mesmo dos desenvolvedores de páginas, mas nos dias de hoje e falando agora de JSF que são aplicações baseadas em componetes você já não depende tanto do designer, bem provável que se usar JSF você irá escolha um desses beans do mercado como como Primefaces, richfaces(acabou), IceFaces, etc... ainda assim é possível mesclar JSTL e outras bibliotecas, mas lembrando que você tem facelets.

Mas enfim, seguir os padrões é bom porque significa que muitos já passaram pelos mesmos problemas que você vai enfrentar se não seguir eles, resultando em um péssimo modelo, acredite, é bem fácil um projeto falhar e basta uma decisão errada nele para estar fadado ao fracasso, por isso estude, se aprimore e faça bom uso dos patterns, mas não por modismo da época e sim porque realmente aquele padrão resolve um problema de uma forma muito elegante e que acima de tudo matém os principios de design.

Comment: Sim, estava sainda de casa para o trabalho quando começei a escrever, sabia também alguém levantaria essa questão :), porém não foi dessa forma que quis me expressar, também não quis comentar que um JSP vira uma servlet etc... pois o assunto iria muito longe, quis apenas enfatizar o quanto é ruim ter código Java no meio de todo HTML,  mas você esta certo há mais processos na request/response.

Comment: removi a parte em que citei isso, obrigado pelo feed-back em apontar o erro.

Comment: Então scriptlet realmente não deve ser usado, o melhor é ter apenas o JSTL no JSP e o que for código Java tem que ser direcionado para a Servlet?

Comment: exatamente @Tadeu F.I e no caso de ser JSF nas versões atuais nem é bom o uso com JSP e sim .xhtml pois o ciclo de vida do JSP não combina bem com faces.